# How to make Three.js ShaderMaterial gradient to transparent

Tags: vue.js, three.js, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I want to make a two-color gradient transparent. In the image below you can see.

[image]

Left is the final mesh and on the right a single face. I'm trying to achieve this with a vertex shader and a fragment shader. But unfortunately, I can't figure it out. Hopefully, somebody can help me

I have this so far:

```
 var custom3Material = new this.$three.ShaderMaterial({
                 uniforms: {
                   vlak3color1: { value: new this.$three.Color('#31c7de')},
                   vlak3color2: {type: 'vec2', value: new this.$three.Color('#de3c31')},
                   positionVlak3: {value: -3.5},
                 },
                 vertexShader: `
                
                   varying vec3 vUv; 

                   void main() {
                     vUv = position; 

                  
                     gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
                   }
                 `,
                 fragmentShader: `
                    
                  uniform vec3 vlak3color1;
                   uniform vec3 vlak3color2;
                   uniform float positionVlak3;

                
                   varying vec3 vUv;
                  
                   void main() {     
                    
                   gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(vlak3color1, vlak3color2, vUv.y-positionVlak3), 1);
                   }
               `,
              });
```

I would like to be able to adjust the position between the 2 colors and the transparency afterward

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You must make your material transparent by adding `transparent: true` to its attributes.
2. `vlak3color2: {type: 'vec2', value: new this.$three.Color('#de3c31')}` is confusing. Why are you trying to make a color of type `vec2`? Just get rid of the type, you don't need it. Three.js automatically recognizes the type when it sees it's a Color.
3. The fourth value of `gl_FragColor` is the alpha. Right now you're setting it to a constant `1`, so you're getting a fully-opaque color. Try to make it fade from 0 - 1 with [`smoothstep()`](https://thebookofshaders.com/glossary/?search=smoothstep):

```js
void main() {
    // y < 0 = transparent, > 1 = opaque
    float alpha = smoothstep(0.0, 1.0, vUv.y);

    // y < 1 = color1, > 2 = color2
    float colorMix = smoothstep(1.0, 2.0, vUv.y);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(vlak3color1, vlak3color2, colorMix), alpha);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Marquizzo, Thanks for the clear explanation, it solved my problem! I had not heard of `smoothstep()`


However, I have another question do you know how to assign in a ShaderMaterial every Face in a geometry a specific color? Now I made 4 separate triangle geometries and assigned separate ShaderMaterials. But I think it should be possible to make 1 geometry consisting of 4 faces and assign 1 ShaderMaterial with every face his own color. Or should I ask a new question for this?

Comment: It's a bit complicated because you need to add a new color `BufferAttribute` per vertex, then read that in the frag shader. You could look at [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=attrib#webgl_buffergeometry_custom_attributes_particles), each point has its own `color` attribute. If you get stuck while reading that example, you should ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks again! I will read that example. yeah I already read something about assigning every vertex a color, but I have to read/learn more about that

Comment: [This article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-custom-buffergeometry.html) covers custom buffer attributes.